# VkNet - Как изъять id человека VK? [С#]

Tags: c#, vknet

Делаю приложение основанное на vk api (VkNet). Любые операции с профилем другого человека производится только если у вас есть его id. Вопрос в следующем - можно ли имея краткую ссылку на вк, сразу, внутри c# запарсить ее в чистый id.

Примерно так:

```
https://vk.com/stephanzion => 438880090
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без запроса к VK API -- никак (см. постскриптум)

Используйте [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get) передавая в user_ids значение screen_names:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS Разумеется, есть ещё варвары, которые прикидываются браузером и потом регулярками выцарапывают id из html... но мы говорим о правильном способе -- использовать API.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы. Это я и имел в виду, разумеется я не стану парсить   такое исключительно C#).